# (WinAPI) Simulating item selection in ComboBox

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, combobox

I am currently writing a wrapper for an existing application that has its own GUI. I don't have access to original application's source code (unfortunately). The program that I am writing is in C++ and I am making use of WinAPI. I am manipulating target application by simulating button-clocks, ticking checkboxes etc.

The problem I am facing at the moment is following:

I need to make a selection in droplist implemented as WinAPI [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I am doing it by using macro [ComboBox_SetCurSel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The selection in the droplist changes correctly. However in the original application there is a read-only textbox that changes the value depending on the selection in combobox. And this one does not change when I execute ComboBox_SetCurSel.

The assumption I made is that [CBN_SELENDOK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [CBN_SELCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are sent when selecting an entry in ComboBox manually and this is the bit I am not doing when setting the selection with ComboBox_SetCurSel macro.

However due to lack of experience I cannot figure out how to resolve the problem. Who is normally listening for CBN_SELENDOK and CBN_SELCHANGE. Is it main application window, parent element of the combobox or main application thread? How do I find out.

Is there a macro that would do the whole thing? Like changing the selected item in ComboBox and sending all necessary notifications? Is there some smart workaround?

Any help on the subject, or any additional questions that would help to make situation more clear are welcome.

UPDATE: thanks for comment by Jonathan Potter. I am now attempting to send messages explicitly. Here is the part of the code where I am doing it:

```
int res = ComboBox_SetCurSel(this->handle, index);
if (res == CB_ERR)
{
    return false;
}
PostMessage(GetParent(this->handle),WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(0,CBN_SELENDOK),0);
PostMessage(GetParent(this->handle),WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(0,CBN_SELCHANGE),0);
```

Note `this->handle` is just a handle to `ComboBox` itself as I have packed it into the structure for convenience. `GetParent(this->handle)` Should get immediate parent of `ComboBox`

Still no result. Does the order of messages matter? Also how do I obtain the identifier that needs to go into LOWORD of WPARAM sent along with WM_COMMAND?

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to **AlwaysLearningNewStuff** I have found and an answer. I have been sending messages with 0 as LPARAM. Apparently a handle to ComboBox itself neets to be sent as LPARAM in order for solution to work. This would take me ages to figure it out.
**@AlwaysLearningNewStuff**, you should have posted this as an answer, not a comment.

Also the bit about using [GetDlgCtrlID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get ControlID of the ComboBox is very useful. This makes code more reliable.

Thank you, everyone who participated.

Here is my final code:

```
if (this->handle == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
int res = ComboBox_SetCurSel(this->handle, index);
if (res == CB_ERR)
{
    return false;
}
PostMessage(GetParent(this->handle), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(GetDlgCtrlID( this->handle ),CBN_SELENDOK),
        (LPARAM)(this->handle));
PostMessage(GetParent(this->handle), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(GetDlgCtrlID( this->handle ),CBN_SELCHANGE),
        (LPARAM)(this->handle));
return true;
```

Comment: Its the immediate parent of the combo box. If you post it a WM_COMMAND message with the appropriate values it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still cannot make it work. I am trying to put together a minimal example. I will update my question shortly

Comment: Try something like `PostMessage( GetParent(this->handle), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM( IDC_OF_YOUR_COMBOBOX, CBN_SELENDOK ), (LPPARAM)this->handle );`or if you do not have an ID of your combobox you could try something like this: `PostMessage( GetParent(this->handle), WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM( GetDlgCtrlID( this->handle ), CBN_SELENDOK ), (LPPARAM)( this->handle ) );`. Best regards.

Comment: I am glad I was helpful. Good luck and best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that `CBN_SELCHANGE` is not sent when using `ComboBox_SetCurSel()`, and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775821.aspx) says as much:

> The CBN_SELCHANGE notification code is **not** sent when the current selection is set using the CB_SETCURSEL message.

So you have to send the notifications manually. However, you are missing key elements in your messages - the ComboBox's **Control ID** and **HWND**.  The parent window uses those to identify which child control is sending messages to it so it can then act accordingly.

Try this instead:

```
int res = ComboBox_SetCurSel(this->handle, index);
if (res == CB_ERR)
{
    return false;
}
HWND hParent = GetParent(this->handle);
int iCtrlId = GetDlgCtrlID(this->handle);
if (GetWindowLong(this->handle, GWL_STYLE) & CBS_SIMPLE)
    PostMessage(hParent, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(iCtrlId,CBN_SELENDOK), LPARAM(this->handle));
PostMessage(hParent, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(iCtrlId,CBN_SELCHANGE), LPARAM(this->handle));
```

Comment: Already answered in comments by AlwaysLearningNewStuff, but you get the "tick" because you have submitted it as a nicely detailed answer. Thanx. By the way, why are you checking the return of `GetWindowLong()` ? I'd assume it exists anyway.

Comment: I am checking `GetWindowLong()` because [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775825.aspx) states the following: "In a combo box with the CBS_SIMPLE style, the CBN_SELENDOK notification code is sent immediately before every CBN_SELCHANGE notification code."

Comment: You may or may not also need to add a check for `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY`.  In the documentation for Windows mobile/CE, it says `CBN_SELENDOK` is not sent when `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` is enabled. But I do not see a similar comment in the Win32 documentation, and I have not tried it myself yet to see if a ComboBox really behaves that way or not.